# mysql count table rows with count child tables rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables. a>b>c tables. I want to totals separately each other and optimize query. My query is not giving the true counts.

*TABLE: a*

```
a
-----------
id
no
create_time
```

*TABLE: b*

```
b
-----------
id
no
```

*TABLE: c*

```
c
-----------
id
b_id
```

*this query is not giving the true counts*

```
SELECT
    DATE( a.create_time ) AS date,
    COUNT( a.id ) AS total_a,
    COUNT( b.id ) AS total_b,
    COUNT( c.id ) AS total_c 
FROM
    `a`
    LEFT JOIN `b` ON `a`.`no` = `b`.`no`
    LEFT JOIN `c` ON `b`.`id` = `c`.`b_id` 
WHERE
    ( `a`.`status` = 1 ) 
GROUP BY
    DATE( a.create_time ) 
ORDER BY
    `date` DESC 
    LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Add Sample data and expected output

Comment: Try correlated sub-queries in the select list.

Comment: Thanks your answers, I solved with that Andomer's answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `left join` repeats each row on the left hand side for each matching row on the right hand side. So you get more rows than in the original.

An easy fix is to count just the unique identifiers:

```
SELECT
    DATE( a.create_time ) AS date,
    COUNT( DISTINCT a.id ) AS total_a,
    COUNT( DISTINCT b.id ) AS total_b,
    COUNT( DISTINCT c.id ) AS total_c
```